# Align text to center with image on the same line

Tags: css

I'm trying to center text that got an image in the same line, and it centers the text with the rest of the line, but not to the center of the browser.

Here's the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Hdn9w/1/

I know i can change:

```
.text1
{
    line-height: 450%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: David;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to:

```
.text1
{
    line-height: 450%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: David;
    margin-left: 550px;
}
```

but that's won't work on different browsers and iphone and stuff, and i'm pretty sure it's possible but i just can't seem to find it.
I'm assuming it's something like "display" or "position" or "overflow" but nothing seem to work..

Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">

            <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://www.saludmedellin.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/dfd1.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="text1">
                Stocks Trader
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="bodier">
            <form>
                <input type="text" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

and the css:

```
body
{
    background-color: #c4dbe5;
}

.header
{
    background-color: #5a9ab7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

.logo img
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.text1
{
    line-height: 450%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: David;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question...you want to center both on the header? Image and text on top of it? Or maybe do you want to vertically align the text?

Comment: No, i want the text to be centered horizontally as if there is no image there.
Like here - http://jsfiddle.net/Hdn9w/8/ that the "Stocks Trader(2)" is fully centered.

Comment: Put the answer there, adding relative and absolute position to the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

-Text horizontal/vertical align to the header:
-Also hide the logo on small screens so it doesnt get in the way.

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/Hdn9w/6/

CSS modifications:

```
body
{
    background-color: #c4dbe5;
}

.header
{
    background-color: #5a9ab7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
}

.logo img
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.text1
{
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: David;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

@media (max-width:480px){
.logo {
    display:none;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow!! yessss thank you very much.
I added the "position: relative;" to the .header and "position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;" to the .text1 and it's working!

Not sure what @media does(something with iphone maybe?) but anyway.. it's working! so thank you!!

Comment: If you set width to the text or other element on this scenario will also need to set "margin:auto" so it center by itself.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.. what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

Use pixels for line-height instead of percents.. in all cases.

```
.text1
{
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: David;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Partial demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pyLSg/

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the reason you want to use those pixel dimensions is because you need to match up with the actual height of the object you're lining up with.

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/Hdn9w/5/

```
.logo {
    float:left;
    /* I'd suggest floating the container, not the image */
}

.logo img
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px; /* also, use margin, not padding, on an img */
    /* remember that total height of this object is: 
          10px (top margin) +
          80px (image) +
          10px (bottom margin) == 100px */
}

.text1
{
    line-height: 100px; /* Your line-height should match the 
                           total height of your .logo img */
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: David;
    text-align: center;
}
```